# display data from json object on HTML in angular 5

Tags: html, json, node.js, angular, mongodb

hello i want to display the data that i got from a mongodb using a backend api (nodejs) 
this is the code for event model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/database');

// Events Schema
const EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  eventname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  eventstartdate: {
    type: String,
    required: true


  },
  eventenddate: {
    type: String,
    required: true


  },

  eventcategorie: {
    type: String


  },
  eventdescription: {
    type: String


  },
  eventimage: {
    type: String


  }


});
const Event = module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

this is the code from the router

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const passport = require('passport');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const config = require ('../config/database');
    const User = require('../models/user');
    const Event = require('../models/event');

    //get event by id
router.get('/event/:eventid', (req,res) => {
  Event.findById(req.params.eventid, (err, event) =>{   
  if (err){
    return res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
  }
  if(!event){
    return res.status(400).send({message:'Event not found'});
  }

  res.json({

    event: {
      id: event._id,
      eventname: event.eventname,
      eventstartdate: event.eventstartdate,
      eventenddate: event.eventenddate,
      eventcategorie: event.eventcategorie,
      eventdescription: event.eventdescription,
      eventimage: event.eventimage

    }

  });
});
});
```

and this is the code from the service in the angular

```
// GET an event by ID
   displayEvent$(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/event/${id}`)
    .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

then i created a simple method that is triggered by a button 
and i passed an id of an event that i konw is in the database just to test it out

```
onclickeventpage(){
    this.authService.displayEvent$('5ae0c8e96b40a71cd3b772cc').subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event)




  });
}
```

this gives me back at the console the event i need with every aribute
but whene i change this

```
console.log(event)
```

to this so i can get evey atribute separetly and then i an put them in the html

```
console.log(event.eventname)
```

i get undefined

i just want to know how to get every event atribute so i can display them in my html page

Comment: You are sending everything under a "key" name `console.log(event.event.eventname)`. Which should probably indicate to you to not send the response like that and simply return the object instead. i.e `res.json(event)` rather than what you have.

Comment: Also, are you using the old `Http Module`? You should look at using the `HttpClient Module` that was introduced in [4.3](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)

Answer (score 0):

First you dont have to call **.json()** witn angular5

```
displayEvent$(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/event/${id}`)
    .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

also you need to access

```
console.log(event.event.eventname);
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpModule` is deprecated and the new `HttpClientModule` by default formats the response to JSON so we no longer need to parse it using `response.json()`:

> I just want to know how to get every event attribute so that I can
>   display them on my HTML page

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

Typechecking of response can be done by  using type parameter

```
 export interface Ievent {
  id:string
  eventname: string
  eventstartdate: string
  eventenddate: string
  eventcategorie: string
  eventdescription: string
  eventimage: string

    }
```

`Http` returns an `observable` and We can tell the `HttpClient.get` to return `response` as Ievent type When we use `http.get<Ievent>(...)` then it returns the instance of `Observable<Ievent>` type. 
In your service

```
     import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import {Ievent} from './eventModel'
            @Injectable()
        export class authService()
                {
       constructor(private http:HttpClient){}
       displayEvent$(id: string)Observable<Ievent> {

          return this.http.get<Ievent>(`http://localhost:3000/users/event/${id}`);
           }
          }
```

In your component subscribe to `Observable<Ievent>` to get instance of Ievent

```
   onclickeventpage(){
    this.authService.displayEvent$('5ae0c8e96b40a71cd3b772cc').subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
      console.log(event.eventname)});
}
```